# First letter of each word capitalized

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, loops

I did a task for FreeCodeCamp. The task is:

> Return the provided string with the first letter of each word capitalized. Make sure the rest of the word is in lower case. 
>   titleCase("I'm a little tea pot") should return a string.
>   titleCase("I'm a little tea pot") should return I'm A Little Tea Pot. 
>   ...

My FreeCodeCamp console.log shows tests like: I'm A Little Tea Pot (which is correct), but it won`t let to me go through to approve this task.

```
function titleCase(str) {

var lower = str.toLowerCase()
var toarray = lower.split(" ")
let i = 0;
for( let i=0; i < toarray.length; i++){

 toarray[i] = toarray[i].slice(0,1).toUpperCase()  + toarray[i].slice(1).toString();

}

console.log(toarray.join(' '))

}

titleCase("I'm a little tea pot");
titleCase("sHoRt AnD sToUt");
```

Comment: Go back and re-read the concept of functions:  how they work and what they must do.

Comment: Hint: "... should _return_ a string" - it doesn't return anything at the moment

Comment: @CherryDT it doesn't *explicitly* return anything. But it does return something - it returns `undefined`.

Answer (score 2):

you need to return it and not just print it